# Sending multiple attachments from excel sheet with VBA

Tags: vba, email, excel, outlook

I have the existing code to send a mail from a Sheet in my Excel file -

```
Sub CreateMail()

    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMail As Object
    Dim rngTo As Range
    Dim rngSubject As Range
    Dim rngBody As Range
    Dim rngAttach As Range

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Worksheets("Mail List").Activate

    With ActiveSheet
        Set rngTo = .Range("B1")
        Set rngSubject = .Range("B2")
        Set rngBody = .Range("B3")
        Set rngAttach = .Range("B4")

    End With

    With objMail
        .To = rngTo.Value
        .Subject = rngSubject.Value
        .body = rngBody.Value
        .Attachments.Add rngAttach.Value
        .display 'Instead of .Display, you can use .Send to send the email _
                    or .Save to save a copy in the drafts folder
    End With

    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    Set objMail = Nothing
    Set rngTo = Nothing
    Set rngSubject = Nothing
    Set rngBody = Nothing
    Set rngAttach = Nothing

End Sub
```

However, I want to include a number of attachments, and hence the 
`Set rngAttach = .Range("B4")` does not help to do this.

Any help on this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is in `B4` - a file path?

Comment: Loop through the range of file paths and add each one in turn.

Comment: You can use `.Attachments.Add` multiple times times to add each attachment. Each time reference it to a different path possibly using a loop.

Comment: @brettdj Yes, B4 has a file path, I have multiple paths in B5, B6 as well, etc

Comment: @Rory Can you help me out with the code ?

Comment: @izzymo Can you help me out with the code ?

Answer (score 1):

Enclose your .Attachments.Add statement in loop. Something like below might work

```
    For i = 4 To 6
      .Attachments.Add Range("B" & i).Value
    Next i
```

Comment: Hi Abhijeet any way I can make this dynamic??

Answer (score 1):

To make it Dynamic you can set the upper limit of i to the last row in Column B

```
For i = 4 To Range("B" & rows.count).end(xlUp).row
  .Attachments.Add Range("B" & i).Value
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

This updated code:

1. Looks for file names from `B4`
2. Uses `Dir` to ensure the attached files actually exist at the specified path
3. Tidies up the worksheet code (`Activate` is unnecessary)

   ```
   Sub CreateMail()

   Dim objOutlook As Object
   Dim objMail As Object
   Dim rngTo As Range
   Dim rngSubject As Range
   Dim rngBody As Range
   Dim rngAttach As Range
   Dim rng2 As Range
   Dim ws As Worksheet


   Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Set ws = Worksheets("Mail List")

   With ws
       Set rngTo = .Range("B1")
       Set rngSubject = .Range("B2")
       Set rngBody = .Range("B3")
       Set rngAttach = ws.Range(ws.[b4], ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
   End With

   With objMail
       .To = rngTo.Value
       .Subject = rngSubject.Value
       .body = rngBody.Value
       For Each rng1 In rngAttach.Cells
           If Len(Dir(rng1)) > 0 Then .Attachments.Add rng1.Value
       Next

       .display 'Instead of .Display, you can use .Send to send the email _
                   or .Save to save a copy in the drafts folder
   End With

   Set objOutlook = Nothing
   Set objMail = Nothing
   Set rngTo = Nothing
   Set rngSubject = Nothing
   Set rngBody = Nothing
   Set rngAttach = Nothing

   End Sub
   ```